# How to keep the header,footer and outer div to be fixed and making the inner div scroll-able

Tags: css, html, scrollable

Please look at this http://jsfiddle.net/jaseem/sS7HN/ . What I am trying to achieve is instead of that inner scroll-bar, I want to use the main window scroll bar; SO that I can use the windows vertical scroll bar to go through the content inside the "innerContent" but at the same time I want the outer div to be fixed. is that possible ?

CSS :

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px; 
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%; 
}

content {
    background-color:#656565;
    width: 940px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-radius:5px; 
}

mainContent {
    margin:0px auto;
    background-color:#515151;
    width:660px;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding-top:20px; 
}   

contentHolder {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:616px;
    background-color:#000000;
    border-radius:10px;
    overflow:auto; 
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="mainContent">
        <div id="contentHolder"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear what you are trying to accomplish, but I did notice you are missing the hash tags in your CSS. You need `#` in front of the identifier if you are referring to an `ID` attribute.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hgcax/

CSS

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px; 
}

#footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%; 
}

#content {
    background-color:#656565;
    width: 940px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-radius:5px; 
}

#mainContent {
    margin:0px auto;
    background-color:#515151;
    width:660px;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding-top:20px; 
}   

#contentHolder {
    color:#fff;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:600px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:#000000;
    border-radius:10px;
    overflow:auto; 
}​
```

Comment: Sorry if I confused you all. Please look at this http://jsfiddle.net/jaseem/sS7HN/ . What I am trying to achieve is instead of that inner scroll-bar, I want to use the main window scroll bar; SO that I can use the windows vertical scroll bar to go through the content inside the "innerContent" but at the same time I want the outer div to be fixed. is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

for div elements you have to give #div name here your div name is contentHolder so its #contentHolder

try like this:

```
#contentHolder {
 overflow:auto; 
}
```

or

```
#contentHolder {
 overflow:scroll; 
}
```

Comment: Please look at this http://jsfiddle.net/jaseem/sS7HN/ . What I am trying to achieve is instead of that inner scroll-bar, I want to use the main window scroll bar; SO that I can use the windows vertical scroll bar to go through the content inside the "innerContent" but at the same time I want the outer div to be fixed. is that possible ?

Comment: then use #header {overflow:auto; }